# Can I use compiled code in a Webpack loader?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, html-webpack-plugin

I'll try to describe the problem I'm trying to solve in order to avoid [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I've got a React application that is transpiled (by either Babel or TypeScript). Now, I've set up Webpack to have it transpiled and then bundled into a single script, and then to update my `index.html` to link to that script. However, I'd also like the build process to do an initial render of the application and to insert *that* into `index.html`.

My attempted solution was to add a custom loader to the `html-webpack-plugin` that requires the React app, renders it and then inserts it into the HTML file. However, now that my React app is not written in Javascript, I can no longer simply `require()` it.

How can I best get it transpiled before rendering it and inserting it into my page?